# How to compare floating point number with two other floating point numbers in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, conditional-statements

When I do the following to compare if the decimal value is between the two values, I get inconsistent results.

```
x = 1.87

if 1.0 >= x < 2.0:
    print("x: ", x, "; cat: high")
    return 'high'
elif 2.0 >= x < 3.0: 
    print("x: ", x, "; cat: medium")
    return 'medium'
elif 3.0 >= x <= 5.0:
    print("x: ", x, "; cat: low")
    return 'low'
else:
    return None
```

I get the `medium` returned as a result. I checked with other values, and none of them matched. I found articles on `math.isclose()`, but it doesn't help me. How do I solve this?

Comment: yeah, because you should check `if 1.0 <= x < 2.0`, and not `if 1.0 >= x < 2.0`

Comment: oh god! What an idiotic and rookie mistake. I didn't even catch it and kept typing. Sorry about that

Comment: No need to apologise, nobody is forced to help!